# populate select picker on live-search event

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using a selectpicker (https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search) that I populate from a rest API.

At this point, I have only 30 entries. however, this number will grow very soon.
I want to start with an empty selectpicker, then, when the user write some text in the live-search input, I populate the selectpicker only with the corresponding items.

for example, if the user writes "al", then I will populate my selectpicker with entries containing "al".
unfortunately, this class does not contain events on live search. Could you suggest another class??

Any input will help

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You will need javascript.

Here an example using jquery:

first in the HTML you need to wrap your select element into a div with id so you can use it's input using the form-control class

```
<div id="my-div">
    <select id="my-select" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"></select>
</div>
```

Now in the javascript file you will need to do the following

```
$('#my-select').selectpicker('refresh');
$('#my-div .form-control').on('keyup', function () {
    //here you listen to the change of the input corresponding to your select
    //and now you can populate your select element


    $('#my-select').append($('<option>', {
        value: 'any value',
        text: 'any text'
    }));
    $('#my-select').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `boostrap-select (or selectpicker)` does not support this yet, I've found a workaround.

This is not the best practice, but it works.

```
 $('#youselectpicker').on('loaded.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
        $(".youselectpicker .bs-searchbox input").on('keyup',function(){
            //place your code here
            //don't forget to refresh the select picker if you change the options
        })
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

My Simple jQuery implementation that works.

```
    jQuery("select[name='select picker name']").siblings().find("input[type='text']").keyup(function (e) {
        if(e.keyCode==13){
           //Code to implement ajax search
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me only this worked in the end:

By combining some of the answers here, my workaround is listening for a click on the dropdown button which is the 'show.bs.select' event in bootstrap, and then listening for input into the input field contained within the div (my_select_outer) I placed the whole selectpicker section in. This input field is created by bootstrap when the selectpicker is clicked on.

```
    $('#my_select').on('show.bs.select',
      function(e) {
            $('#my_select_outer .form-control').on('input', function() {
                $('#my_select').empty();
                $('#my_select').selectpicker('refresh');
                let contains = $('#my_select_outer .form-control').val();
                // run API call based on 'contains'
                });
          })
    });
```